# Extracting Ints from Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, int

I'm trying to write a method which takes a String, looks for Ints in it
and then adds them together.

*for example:*

```
    String s = "five5six66"
```

should return 5+66 = 71 or:

```
    String s = "1ciao2three3"
```

should return 1+2+3 = 6

The following is what I wrote already, but when I run it I get a

```
    NumberFormatException
```

code (Update 1):

```
    public static int addNumbers(String s) {
    String numbers="";
    int addNumbers = 0;
    int i;
    char c;

    for (i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i)>='0' && s.charAt(i)<='9') {
            c = s.charAt(i);
            while (i<s.length()-1) {
                if (s.charAt(i+1)>='0' && s.charAt(i+1)<='9')
                    numbers = numbers.valueOf(c + s.charAt(i+1));
                addNumbers = addNumbers + Integer.parseInt(numbers);
            }
            addNumbers = addNumbers + Character.getNumericValue(c);
        }
    }
    return addNumbers;
}
```

Hopefully you can help me fix this code and please, let me understand what I did wrong!

Also can I expand it so if I have a String like:

```
    String s = "hi123and27"
```

I can get 123+27 = 150?

Because my code is limited to a 2 digit number as it is now.

Comment: consider using regex for that method

Comment: This: `s.charAt(i+1)` is a **very** dangerous thing to do inside of that for loop. Think on why, and the issue should become obvious.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks I got it! That is why I get the IndexOutOfBound but how can I concatenate 2 consecutive numbers in a String then?

Comment: You could store the char in a variable and if the next char remains a digit, concatenate them -- i.e., look behind but don't look ahead. You're running into "boundary conditions" and you need to think through them carefully.

Comment: Ok! I'll try and update my code!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've tried this way but now I get a NumberFormatException... Another off topic question, should I update my code leaving the previous one or just overwrite it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try this one.

```
public static int addNum(String text){
    String numbers = "";
    int finalResult = 0;

    for(int i=0;i < text.length();i++){

        if(isNumeric(text.substring(i, i + 1)))
        {
            numbers += text.substring(i, i + 1);

            if(i==text.length()-1) {
                finalResult += Integer.parseInt(numbers); 
            }
        }else {
            if(!numbers.equals("")){
                finalResult += Integer.parseInt(numbers);
                numbers = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return finalResult;
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
  try{  
    int d = Integer.parseInt(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException ex){  
    return false;  
  }
  return true;  
}
```

Comment: I like your answer and I'm testing it. Could you explain me how try and catch works?

Comment: Tried this. for s = "75sg1kjhgd23" I get 7+5+1+2+3 = 18. I need 75+1+23 = 99

Comment: Try catch blocks are used to catch exceptions so whenever an exception occurs in try block statement the control of execution is passed to the catch block. That's not possible because I've tried it and I'm getting 99 as result.

Comment: Ok I don't know why it didn't work before. probably I mistyped something. What does the += mean? in finalResult += Integer.parseInt(numbers);

Comment: shortcut for:
    finalResult = finalResult + Integer.parseInt(numbers);

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using REGEX to address your requirements:

you will need:

1. the REGEX pattern: **"\d+"**
2. an accumulator that is concatenating the value you get of the given String

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hi123and27";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int accumulator  = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        accumulator  += Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println("final result: " + accumulator );
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginner to Java and development in general, I'd like to use something more "basic" thanks for you answer anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Regex + Java 8 streams:

```
public static int addNumbers(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ").split(" "))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .sum();
}
```

EDIT regarding recommendations is the comments:

```
public static int addNumbers(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("[^0-9]+"))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: What's the point in replacing every non-digit character with another one to split on the other character? Just split on the non-digit characters and skip the redundant `replaceAll` call. And use `[^0-9]+` instead of `[^0-9]` to reduce the amount of empty entries (less `s.isEmpty()` checks).

Comment: @Tom your point is correct, {replaceAll} is really not necessary here, I'll update the answer regarding your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    String string = "hi123and27";

    int size = string.length();

    int sum = 0;
    StringBuilder val = new StringBuilder();

    for (int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++) {
        Character character = string.charAt(idx);

        if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
            val.append(character);

            //if last character is a digit
            if((idx+1 == size) && val.length() > 0)
                sum += Integer.parseInt(val.toString());

        }else{
            if(val.length() > 0)
                sum += Integer.parseInt(val.toString());

            //reset the val for digits between characters for it to store the next sequence
            val.setLength(0);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The sum is : " + sum);
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work. This are the results I'm getting:  jhdsg1kjhgd2 - [3] = 2 and
 75sg1kjhgd23 - [99] = 23

Comment: Please check again, just executed  String s = "hi123and27" and I got 150, actually I have executed all the examples you gave 75sg1kjhgd23=99, and five5six66=71, 1ciao2three3=6

Comment: Thanks it worked! Another question, In     'sum += Integer.parseInt(val.toString());' what does     '+=' mean?

Comment: Just shortcut for: sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(val.toString());  Please up vote the answer.